# Listing a persons latest updates

Tags: php, mysql

The query is listing all updates. I only want to list the latest update not every update a person have done

```
SELECT DISTINCT  updated, name  
    FROM table 
    WHERE updated > '$toDay'  
    GROUP BY updated DESC, name ASC;
```

This is how it's being listed now :

```
15-12-2011 Gary     
10-12-2011 Anna 
09-12-2011 John
08-12-2011 John
07-12-2011 Gary
05-10-2010 Gary
```

This is how I wont it to be listed:

```
15-12-2011 Gary     
10-12-2011 Anna 
09-12-2011 John
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT MAX(updated) AS MaxUpdate, name
    FROM table
    WHERE updated > '$toDay'
    GROUP BY name
    ORDER BY MaxUpdate DESC, name ASC;
```

Comment: It Works great!

Thanx for taking your time and helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  name,   MAX(updated) as last_update, 
FROM table 
WHERE updated > '$toDay'  
GROUP BY name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT  MAX(updated), name  
    FROM table 
    WHERE updated > '$toDay'  
    GROUP BY updated DESC, name ASC;
```

[MAX([DISTINCT] expr)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max)

Returns the maximum value of expr. MAX() may take a string argument; in such cases, it returns the maximum string value.

Comment: Thanx for taking your time and helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY`, may be the soluction!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you confused the GROUP BY and ORDER BY syntax.

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT updated, name 
FROM table 
WHERE updated > '$toDay' 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY updated DESC, name ASC;
```

Additionally, you can check the SQL articles:

[GROUPY BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

[ORDER BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)

Comment: Thanx for taking your time and helping me out!